# How do I add a namespace to an existing project?

Tags: apex, namespace

So I have been working on my project for 2 months. Now we are finally ready to start the process whereby we will bundle it up as a managed package and then release it into the Salesforce App Store.

I've read that I need to get a namespace. I am curious how I add this in now?

If I look here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespaces_creating.htm

I see some instructions for those of us who have a Developer edition. But I also see this text:

```
This button doesn’t appear if you’ve already configured your developer settings.
```

And I can not find that button.

Where do I look?

Also, do I have to change my code to use the namespace prefix everywhere? For instance, I have some controllers that use other utility code, like this:

So I have been working on my project for 2 months. Now we are finally ready to start the process whereby we will bundle it up as a managed package and then release it into the Salesforce App Store.

I've read that I need to get a namespace. I am curious how I add this in now?

If I look here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespaces_creating.htm

I see some instructions for those of us who have a Developer edition. But I also see this text:

```
This button doesn’t appear if you’ve already configured your developer settings.
```

And I can not find that button.

Where do I look?

Also, do I have to change my code to use the namespace prefix everywhere? For instance, I have some controllers that use other utility code, like this:

```
    public class HeddySearchResultController {

    public String baseUrl { get; set; }
    public Search__c currentSearch { get; set; }
    public List<Map<String, String>> currentResults { get; set; }
    public HeddySession__c ps  { get; set; }


    class HeddyAccessException extends Exception {}


    public HeddySearchResultController() {
        // baseUrl is used by the Javascript in the VisualForce page
        String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();

        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        currentSearch = (id == null) ? new Search__c() : [SELECT Name FROM Search__c WHERE Id = :id];

    ps = HeddySessionModel.findCurrentSession();
   }
```

So if I get the namespace "Heddy" do I need to change this:

```
    ps = HeddySessionModel.findCurrentSession();
```

to this:

```
    ps = Heddy__HeddySessionModel.findCurrentSession();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Lightning components (Same as Managed Package)**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespaces_creating.htm

> Create a namespace for your organization by registering a namespace
>   prefix. If you’re not creating managed packages for distribution then
>   registering a namespace prefix isn’t required, but it’s a best
>   practice for all but the smallest organizations.

**Managed Package**

You need to create a package and then you can pick your namespace:

Setup -> Create -> Packages

Then under Developer Settings click "Edit" and follow instructions:

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_packages.htm&language=en_US&type=0

As for changing your code, when you package it references to fields and other metadata will have the namespace appended. ***However*** it is best practice to update your references in your code to use the namespace.

in your example you would change your code to this:

```
ps = Heddy.HeddySessionModel.findCurrentSession();
```

- Classes use the ***ns.***
- Fields and SObjects use ***ns__***

Comment: In this case, the difference between a class and an object is whether I've instantiated the class as an object? What would that look like for an object? Or do you mean sObject?

Comment: @LRK9 - SObject (dang autocorrect)